# Batching actions for caching and performance while avoiding the dirty work

Tags: caching, haskell, optimization, batch-processing, memoization

Say I have two pure but unsafe functions, that do the same, but one of them is working on batches, and is asymptotically faster:

```
f :: Int -> Result -- takes O(1) time
f = unsafePerformIO ...
g :: [Int] -> [Result] -- takes O(log n) time
g = unsafePerformIO ...
```

A naive implementation:

```
getUntil :: Int -> [Result]
getUntil 0 = f 0
getUntil n = f n : getUntil n-1
```

`switch` is the `n` value where `g` gets cheaper than `f`.

`getUntil` will in practice be called with ever increasing `n`, but it might not start at `0`. So since the Haskell runtime can memoize `getUntil`, performance will be optimal if `getUntil` is called with an interval lower than `switch`. But once the interval gets larger, this implementation is slow.

In an imperative program, I guess I would make a TreeMap (which could quickly be checked for  gaps) for caching all calls. On cache misses, it would get filled with the results of `g`, if the gap was greater than `switch` in length, and `f` otherwise, respectively.

How can this be optimized in Haskell?

I think I am just looking for:

- an ordered map filled on-demand using a fill function that would fill all values up to the requested index using one function if the missing range is small, another if it is large
- a get operation on the map which returns a list of all lower values up to the requested index. This would result in a function similar to `getUntil` above.

Comment: `fOrG xs = if length xs < switch then map f xs else g xs`? Or maybe I don't understand the question yet.

Comment: "So since the Haskell runtime can memoize `getUntil` ..." It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking, but note that the Haskell runtime *won't* memoize a function such as `getUntil` unless you write it specifically in a way that will enable memoization.

Comment: @kosmikus, okay, well, if getUntil won't get memoized, then this version is even less optimized than I thought it was. But if we imagined that it *was* memoized, it still wouldn't be efficient, for the reasons listed.

Comment: @DanielWagner, the problem is that I don't know how to formulate "getUntil" so that it returns a list of the f or g on all previous n. The function here doesn't know which n's are cached and which aren't (if you imagine that getUntil were memoized, which it seems it isn't).

Comment: In this particular case, can't you use `getUntil = map f [0 ..]` ? There would be no need to store caches and the like. When required, just use `take n getUntil`.

Comment: You'd get the results in reverse order, nonetheless.

Comment: @ArielD.MoyaSequeira it's all about optimization, so the cache is essential... f is only fast when I I'm not missing a lot of data. I know I wrote O(1), but the constant is big... That's why I talks about the moment the one function is faster. The output order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll elaborate in my proposal for using `map`, after some tests I just ran.

```
import System.IO
import System.IO.Unsafe
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad

switch :: Int
switch = 1000

f :: Int -> Int
f x = unsafePerformIO $ do
    threadDelay $ 500 * x
    putStrLn $ "Calculated from scratch: f(" ++ show x ++ ")"
    return $ 500*x

g :: Int -> Int
g x = unsafePerformIO $ do
    threadDelay $ x*x `div` 2
    putStrLn $ "Calculated from scratch: g(" ++ show x ++ ")"
    return $ x*x `div` 2

cachedFG :: [Int]
cachedFG = map g [0 .. switch] ++ map f [switch+1 ..]

main :: IO ()
main = forever $ getLine >>= print . (cachedFG !!) . read
```

… where `f`, `g` and `switch` have the same meaning indicated in the question.

The above program can be compiled as is using GHC. When executed, positive integers can be entered, followed by a newline, and the application will print some value based on the number entered by the user plus some extra indication on what values are being calculated from scratch.

A short session with this program is:

```
User:     10000 
Program:  Calculated from scratch: f(10000)
Program:  5000000
User:     10001
Program:  Calculated from scratch: f(10001)
Program:  5000500
User:     10000
Program:  5000000
^C
```

The program has to be killed/terminated manually.

Notice that the last value entered doesn't show a "calculated from scratch" message. This indicates that the program has the value cached/memoized somewhere. You can try executing this program yourself; but have into account that `threadDelay`'s lag is proportional to the value entered.

The `getUntil` function then could be implemented using:

```
getUntil :: Int -> [Int]
getUntil n = take n cachedFG
```

or:

```
getUntil :: Int -> [Int]
getUntil = flip take cachedFG
```

If you don't know the value for `switch`, you can try evaluating `f` and `g` in parallel and use the fastest result, but that's another show.